# Numpy array adding a column

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Kind of new to python and I need to use numpy to append a column, I have an ndarray a with `[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]` and another ndarray with b `[1 7]` so the end result should be `[[1 2 3 1] [4 5 6 7]` . I have tried

```
array = np.append(a , b, axis=1)
```

but I get

> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

(makes sense). I was also trying to insert it in a for loop but based on what i have seen with python these libraries have an easy way to do things and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `numpy.hstack` with added axis to b -

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([1,7])

np.hstack([a,b[:,None]])
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

**Notes:**

1. `b[:,None]` adds an axis to turn b from 1D `(2,)` to 2D `(2,1)` array (its the same as `b.reshape(-1,1)`)
2. `np.hstack` is now able to horizontally stack `(2,3)` and `(2,1)` to give `(2,4)` shaped array

Comment: Ah I see thank you, and the resulting is another ndarray ? . and does it work with  any array size and dimension? (for a forexample, b will always be 1D)

Comment: Depends. for np.hstack, you will need the first dimension to be common. as long as the number of rows in a and the number of elements in b are equal .. yes.

Comment: Do mark the answer if he solved your question :) It encourages me to help you again in the future!